# How can I merge many SQLite databases?

Tags: database, sqlite

If I have a large number of SQLite databases, all with the same schema, what is the best way to merge them together in order to perform a query on all databases?

I know it is possible to use [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to do this but it has [a limit](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_attached) of 32 and 64 databases depending on the memory system on the machine.

Answer (score 111):

To summarize from the [Nabble post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120615034014/http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Attempting-to-merge-large-databases-td39548.html) in DavidM's answer:

```
attach 'c:\test\b.db3' as toMerge;           
BEGIN; 
insert into AuditRecords select * from toMerge.AuditRecords; 
COMMIT; 
detach toMerge;
```

Repeat as needed.

*Note: added `detach toMerge;` as per mike's comment.*

Comment: and also `detach toMerge;` *after* committing.

Comment: This would only merge one table I suppose. How would you import multiple tables at once, preserving their foreignkey ?

Comment: I tried this, but the columns from the attached db where misaligned for some reason and the the result was wrong. Therefore, I had to explicitely state column names in the same order in the INSERT and SELECT statements.

Comment: How to cope with UNIQUE constraint and update rows which have same specific columns?

Comment: how do you do this in a script for a dynamic number of databases?

Comment: @user5359531 I would write something in some other language (like python) to emit the SQL commands to do this as above, get the SQL, run the SQL.

Comment: @Mithril To avoid an "Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: xxx.id", replace the
insert statement with
"insert into AuditRecords (column1, column2, .. columnN) select column1, column2, .. columnN from toMerge.AuditRecords; "

Comment: To accomplish this with more than one table all-at-once, while also eliminating the cause of UNIQUE constraint problems (i.e. duplicates) - use the UNION operation: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/  (e.g. accach 'a.db' as a; attach 'b.db' as b; BEGIN; insert into table select * from a.table UNION select * from b.table; COMMIT;

Comment: These apparently make it 100x faster, by the way (at the risk of data corruption if anything interrupts it, and probably cannot read from the target DB at the same time): PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;

Comment: I had to remove the BEGIN;
Just did the seperate steps and it worked. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ILoveCoding I managed a generalized solution that considers foreign keys at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77385110/895245

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple python code to either merge two database files or scan a directory to find all database files and merge them all together (by simply inserting all data in other files to the first database file found).Note that this code just attaches the databases with the same schema.

```
import sqlite3
import os


def merge_databases(db1, db2):
    con3 = sqlite3.connect(db1)

    con3.execute("ATTACH '" + db2 +  "' as dba")

    con3.execute("BEGIN")
    for row in con3.execute("SELECT * FROM dba.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"):
        combine = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO "+ row[1] + " SELECT * FROM dba." + row[1]
        print(combine)
        con3.execute(combine)
    con3.commit()
    con3.execute("detach database dba")


def read_files(directory):
    fname = []
    for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(directory):
        for f in f_names:
            c_name = os.path.join(root, f)
            filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(c_name)
            if (file_extension == '.sqlitedb'):
                fname.append(c_name)

    return fname

def batch_merge(directory):
    db_files = read_files(directory)
    for db_file in db_files[1:]:
        merge_databases(db_files[0], db_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    batch_merge('/directory/to/database/files')
```

Comment: for db_file in db_files[1:]:

Comment: Just adapt the extension if your file didnt have the same as the code, and it works perfectly.

Comment: When I tried to merge two db files which contain different tables, I got the error sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: names.id.  It turned out that if a table doesn't exist in the db1, the insert statement was trying to insert data into the db2 instead of db1.  So I had to add some codes to create the table first in db1.

Comment: This made me run into an `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "-": syntax error` error when the `merge_databases` function tried to merge the history tables. I had to change the following line:   `for row in con3.execute("SELECT * FROM dba.sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name NOT LIKE 'History_%'" ):`

Answer (score 11):

Although a very old thread, this is still a relevant question in today's programming needs. I am posting this here because none of the answers provided yet is concise, easy, and straight-to-point. This is for sake of Googlers that end up on this page. GUI we go:

1. Download [Sqlitestudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt?act=download)
2. Add all your database files by using the `Ctrl + O` keyboard shortcut
3. Double-click each now-loaded db file to open/activate/expand them all
4. Fun part: simply right-click on each of the tables and click on `Copy`, and then go to the target database in the list of the loaded database files (or create new one if required) and right-click on the target db and click on `Paste`

I was wowed to realize that such a daunting task can be solved using the ancient programming skill called: copy-and-paste :)

Comment: I just tried it and it says the object already exists and to enter a new unique name?

Comment: not a good solution for hundreds of files... that why we use the programming skills!

Comment: @GuillermoOlmedo The focus point of my answer was made very clear, i.e. _GUI we go_. I intentionally included that phrase. Please note that.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, sqlite3

class sqlMerge(object):
    """Basic python script to merge data of 2 !!!IDENTICAL!!!! SQL tables"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(sqlMerge, self).__init__()

        self.db_a = None
        self.db_b = None

    def loadTables(self, file_a, file_b):
        self.db_a = sqlite3.connect(file_a)
        self.db_b = sqlite3.connect(file_b)

        cursor_a = self.db_a.cursor()
        cursor_a.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")

        table_counter = 0
        print("SQL Tables available: \n===================================================\n")
        for table_item in cursor_a.fetchall():
            current_table = table_item[0]
            table_counter += 1
            print("-> " + current_table)
        print("\n===================================================\n")

        if table_counter == 1:
            table_to_merge = current_table
        else:
            table_to_merge = input("Table to Merge: ")

        return table_to_merge

    def merge(self, table_name):
        cursor_a = self.db_a.cursor()
        cursor_b = self.db_b.cursor()

        new_table_name = table_name + "_new"

        try:
            cursor_a.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + new_table_name + " AS SELECT * FROM " + table_name)
            for row in cursor_b.execute("SELECT * FROM " + table_name):
                print(row)
                cursor_a.execute("INSERT INTO " + new_table_name + " VALUES" + str(row) +";")

            cursor_a.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name);
            cursor_a.execute("ALTER TABLE " + new_table_name + " RENAME TO " + table_name);
            self.db_a.commit()

            print("\n\nMerge Successful!\n")

        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print("ERROR!: Merge Failed")
            cursor_a.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + new_table_name);

        finally:
            self.db_a.close()
            self.db_b.close()

        return

    def main(self):
        print("Please enter name of db file")
        file_name_a = input("File Name A:")
        file_name_b = input("File Name B:")

        table_name = self.loadTables(file_name_a, file_name_b)
        self.merge(table_name)

        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = sqlMerge()
    app.main()
```

---

SRC :  [Tool to merge identical SQLite3 databases](https://github.com/kd8bny/sqlMerge)

Comment: Does this merges the two databases or drop all from slave and insert all from master database ? If it does that, a simple file copy does the same but faster. The point is to merge only the differences...

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do this merge operation once (to create a new bigger database), you could create a script/program that will loop all your sqlite databases and then insert the data into your main (big) database.

Comment: do you have an example of the code that would perform this action?

Answer (score 0):

**Bash helper that automatically merges all tables from each DB**

Here's a concise Bash version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68526717/895245 that loops over all tables of the given DBs that have the same schema:

sqlite-merge-dbs

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
outdb="$1"
shift
indb0="$1"
shift
cp "$indb0" "$outdb"
for table in $(sqlite3 "$outdb" "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"); do
  echo "table: $table"
  for db in "$@"; do
    echo "db: $db"
    sqlite3 "$outdb" "attach '$db' as 'db2'" "insert into \"$table\" select * from \"db2\".\"$table\""
  done
done
```

This works by extracting the table names from the special `sqlite_master` table.

Sample usage:

```
sqlite-merge-dbs out.sqlite in0.sqlite in1.sqlite in2.sqlite
```

Test:

```
rm -f in0.sqlite in1.sqlite in2.sqlite

sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'create table t(i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'create table t(i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'create table t(i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'insert into t values (1, -1), (2, -2)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into t values (3, -3), (4, -4)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'insert into t values (5, -5), (6, -6)'

sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'create table s(k integer, l integer)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'create table s(k integer, l integer)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'create table s(k integer, l integer)'
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'insert into s values (11, -11), (12, -12)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into s values (13, -13), (14, -14)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'insert into s values (15, -15), (16, -16)'

./sqlite-merge-dbs out.sqlite in0.sqlite in1.sqlite in2.sqlite

sqlite3 out.sqlite 'select * from t'
echo
sqlite3 out.sqlite 'select * from s'
```

Output:

```
1|-1
2|-2
3|-3
4|-4
5|-5
6|-6

11|-11
12|-12
13|-13
14|-14
15|-15
16|-16
```

A Python version of the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import argparse
import sqlite3
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('out')
parser.add_argument('ins', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

shutil.copyfile(args.ins[0], args.out)
con = sqlite3.connect(args.out)
cur = con.cursor()
tables = list(map(lambda e: e[0], cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")))
for db2 in args.ins[1:]:
    cur.execute(f"attach '{db2}' as 'db2'")
    for table in tables:
        cur.execute(f"insert into {table} select * from db2.{table}")
    con.commit()
    cur.execute("detach database db2")
```

**Bash helper that also skips autoincremented columns**

The `sqlite-merge-dbs` script may undesirably blow up if there are autoincremented PK columns in the tables which overlap.

The following helper overcomes that by looking into the `pragma table_info` helper to decide if columns are autoincremented, and skips those from the merge, letting them be re-autoincremented at the end.

sqlite-merge-dbs-id

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
outdb="$1"
shift
indb0="$1"
shift
cp "$indb0" "$outdb"
for table in $(sqlite3 "$outdb" "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"); do
  echo "table: $table"
  cols="$(sqlite3 "$outdb" "pragma table_info($table)" | awk -F\| '{ if ( $3!="INTEGER" || $6=="0" ) { print $2 } else { print "NULL" } }' | paste -sd , -)"
  echo $cols
  for db in "$@"; do
    echo "db: $db"
    sqlite3 "$outdb" "attach '$db' as 'db2'" "insert into \"$table\" select $cols from \"db2\".\"$table\""
  done
done
```

Test:

```
rm -f in0.sqlite in1.sqlite in2.sqlite

sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'create table t(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'create table t(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'create table t(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'insert into t values (NULL, 1, -1), (NULL, 2, -2)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into t values (NULL, 3, -3), (NULL, 4, -4)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'insert into t values (NULL, 5, -5), (NULL, 6, -6)'

sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'create table s(id integer primary key, k integer, l integer)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'create table s(id integer primary key, k integer, l integer)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'create table s(id integer primary key, k integer, l integer)'
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'insert into s values (NULL, 11, -11), (NULL, 12, -12)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into s values (NULL, 13, -13), (NULL, 14, -14)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'insert into s values (NULL, 15, -15), (NULL, 16, -16)'

./sqlite-merge-dbs-id out.sqlite in0.sqlite in1.sqlite in2.sqlite

sqlite3 out.sqlite 'select * from t'
echo
sqlite3 out.sqlite 'select * from s'
```

Output:

```
1|1|-1
2|2|-2
3|3|-3
4|4|-4
5|5|-5
6|6|-6

1|11|-11
2|12|-12
3|13|-13
4|14|-14
5|15|-15
6|16|-16
```

`pragma table_info` is documented at: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

> Columns in the result set include: "name" (its name); "type" (data type if given, else ''); "notnull" (whether or not the column can be NULL); "dflt_value" (the default value for the column); and "pk" (either zero for columns that are not part of the primary key, or the 1-based index of the column within the primary key).

We can observe it in this example with:

```
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'pragma table_info(t)'
```

which outputs:

```
0|id|INTEGER|0||1
1|i|INTEGER|0||0
2|j|INTEGER|0||0
```

and in the script we just skip over anything that is both `INTEGER` and a pk.

A Python version of the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import argparse
import sqlite3
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('out')
parser.add_argument('ins', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

shutil.copyfile(args.ins[0], args.out)
con = sqlite3.connect(args.out)
cur = con.cursor()
tables = list(map(lambda e: e[0], cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")))
table_to_pk_col = {}
table_to_insert = {}
table_to_cols = {}
for table in tables:
    cols = cur.execute(f'pragma table_info({table})').fetchall()
    table_to_cols[table] = cols
    for row in cols:
        col_name = row[1]
        type_ = row[2]
        pk = row[5]
        if type_ == 'INTEGER' and pk != 0:
            if table in table_to_pk_col:
                del table_to_pk_col[table]
            else:
                table_to_pk_col[table] = col_name
table_to_insert = { table: ','.join(list(map(
    lambda c: 'NULL' if c[1] == table_to_pk_col.get(table, None) else c[1], table_to_cols[table]
))) for table in tables }
for db2 in args.ins[1:]:
    cur.execute(f"attach '{db2}' as 'db2'")
    cur.execute(f"begin")
    for table in tables:
        cur.execute(f"insert into {table} select {table_to_insert[table]} from db2.{table}")
    con.commit()
    cur.execute("detach database db2")
```

**Preserve foreign keys to autoincrement pks**

OK, this is the boss level!!! Bash was getting too cumbersome so I pulled out some Python:

sqlite-merge-dbs-id-ref.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import argparse
import sqlite3
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('out')
parser.add_argument('ins', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

shutil.copyfile(args.ins[0], args.out)
con = sqlite3.connect(args.out)
cur = con.cursor()
tables = list(map(lambda e: e[0], cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")))
table_to_pk_col = {}
table_to_insert = {}
table_to_cols = {}
table_to_pk_count = {}
table_to_col_to_foreign = {}
for table in tables:
    col_to_foreign = {}
    table_to_col_to_foreign[table] = col_to_foreign
    cols = cur.execute(f'pragma foreign_key_list({table})').fetchall()
    for col in cols:
        col_name = col[3]
        target_table = col[2]
        col_to_foreign[col_name] = target_table
for table in tables:
    cols = cur.execute(f'pragma table_info({table})').fetchall()
    table_to_cols[table] = cols
    for row in cols:
        col_name = row[1]
        type_ = row[2]
        pk = row[5]
        if type_ == 'INTEGER' and pk != 0:
            if table in table_to_pk_col:
                del table_to_pk_col[table]
            else:
                table_to_pk_col[table] = col_name
    if table in table_to_pk_col:
        table_to_pk_count[table] = cur.execute(f'select max({table_to_pk_col[table]}) from {table}').fetchone()[0]
    else:
        table_to_pk_count[table] = cur.execute(f'select count(*) from {table}').fetchone()[0]
def inc_str(table, col):
    if table in table_to_col_to_foreign:
        col_to_foreign = table_to_col_to_foreign[table]
        if col in col_to_foreign:
            return f'+{table_to_pk_count[col_to_foreign[col]]}'
    return ''
for db2 in args.ins[1:]:
    cur.execute(f"attach '{db2}' as 'db2'")
    table_to_pk_count_inc = {}
    for table in tables:
        table_to_insert = {
            table: ','.join(list(map(
                lambda c: 'NULL' if c[1] == table_to_pk_col.get(table, None) else \
                    c[1] + inc_str(table, c[1]),
                table_to_cols[table]
            ))) for table in tables
        }
        cur.execute(f"insert into {table} select {table_to_insert[table]} from db2.{table}")
        table_to_pk_count_inc[table] = cur.rowcount
    for table in tables:
        table_to_pk_count[table] += table_to_pk_count_inc[table]
    con.commit()
    cur.execute("detach database db2")
```

The script supposes that any `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` that is also the only pk of the table is autoincremented.

This is the test we need to pass, which has tables `t` and `s` linked up by table `ref` with foreign keys to both:

```
rm -f in0.sqlite in1.sqlite in2.sqlite

sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'create table t(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'create table t(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'create table t(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'insert into t values (1, 1, -1), (2, 2, -2), (3, 0, 0)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into t values (1, 3, -3), (2, 4, -4), (3, 0, 0)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'insert into t values (1, 5, -5), (2, 6, -6), (3, 0, 0)'

sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'create table s(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'create table s(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'create table s(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'insert into s values (1, 1, -1), (2, 2, -2)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into s values (1, 3, -3), (2, 4, -4)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'insert into s values (1, 5, -5), (2, 6, -6)'

for i in 0 1 2; do
  sqlite3 "in$i.sqlite" <<EOF
create table ref(
  k integer,
  l integer,
  primary key(k, l),
  foreign key(k) references t(id),
  foreign key(l) references s(id)
)
EOF
done
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'insert into ref values (1, 2)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into ref values (1, 2)'
sqlite3 in2.sqlite 'insert into ref values (1, 2)'

./sqlite-merge-dbs-id-ref.py out.sqlite in0.sqlite in1.sqlite in2.sqlite

echo t
sqlite3 out.sqlite 'select * from t'
echo s
sqlite3 out.sqlite 'select * from s'
echo ref
sqlite3 out.sqlite 'select * from ref'
```

Output:

```
t
1|1|-1
2|2|-2
3|0|0
4|3|-3
5|4|-4
6|0|0
7|5|-5
8|6|-6
9|0|0
+ echo

s
1|1|-1
2|2|-2
3|3|-3
4|4|-4
5|5|-5
6|6|-6
+ echo

ref
1|2
4|4
7|6
```

So now we see that tables `t` and `s` got their PKs increment as before, but for `ref` something more complex happened: the script increments the foreign keys accordingly with PK increments, so we've maintained the relations correctly.

E.g. line:

```
4|4
```

from `ref` links up `4|3|-3` from `t` and `4|4|-4` from `s`. And these values were previously linked up before the merge with:

```
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into ref values (1, 2)'
```

which linked up values from:

```
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into t values (1, 3, -3), (2, 4, -4), (3, 0, 0)'
sqlite3 in1.sqlite 'insert into s values (1, 3, -3), (2, 4, -4)'
```

But on the joined table, the IDs are now 4 and 4 rather than 1 and 2, and we've correctly accounted for that.

The script relies on the `forign_key_list` pragma to list foreign keys https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list E>g.:

```
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'pragma foreign_key_list(ref)'
```

gives:

```
0|0|s|l|id|NO ACTION|NO ACTION|NONE
1|0|t|k|id|NO ACTION|NO ACTION|NONE
```

For reference, `table_info` gives:

```
sqlite3 in0.sqlite 'pragma table_info(s)'
```

Gives:

```
0|k|INTEGER|0||1
1|l|INTEGER|0||2
```

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04, sqlite 3.40.1.

Answer (score -2):

If you have reached the bottom of this feed and yet didn't find your solution, here is also a way to merge the tables of 2 or more sqlite databases.

First try to download and install [DB browser for sqlite database](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). Then try to open your databases in 2 windows and try merging them by simply **drag and drop** tables from one to another. But the problem is that you can just drag and drop only **one** table at a time and therefore its not really a solution for this answer specifically but yet it can used to save some time from further searches if your database is small.

Answer (score -15):

With no offense, just as one developer to another, I'm afraid that your idea seems terribly inefficient.
It seems to me that instead of uniting SQLite databases you should probably be storing several tables within the same Database file.

However if I'm mistaken I guess you could ATTACH the databases and then use a VIEW to simplify your queries. Or make an in-memory table and copy over all the data (but that's even worse performance wise, especially if you have large databases)

Comment: Merging two databases is useful when a database engineer is working with a different copy, in order to modify the structure or content in certain ways, and in the meantime the older, live version is being modified by users.

Comment: I appreciate such feedback, but this would be better suited to a comment on the original question, rather than an "answer".