# Problem with dump command using DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: database, dump, db-browser-sqlite

I am relatively new to SQlite3. I am currently using DB Browser. I have two very large .db files that I want to combine such that a all the tables (all different) all reside together in one .db (ie- I don't want to just attach them).
I am trying to use a simple .dump code in order to achieve this, but keep getting errors. I first define the path/directory and then:

```
for db in OctoberData, OctoberData2; { sqlite3 ${db}.db .dump | sqlite3 OctoberDataAll.db }
```

and get
Result: near "for": syntax error
At line 1:
for

Im sure it is something simple, but what am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This link could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349659/fastest-way-merge-two-sqlite-databases