# how to attach another sqlite db to $dbh with Perl dbd-sqlite

Tags: perl, sqlite

How to attach several sqlite databases into a single $dbh in Perl? In the command line I can do attach in the interactive sqlite3 rpel, how about with dbd-sqlite in Perl?

Sorry if this has been already answer here, perlmonks or similar but was not able to find a proper answer.

Comment: Why do you think you can load multiple databases at once with one instance of dbd-sqlite ?

Comment: I don't know. I was hopping that dbd-sql had implemented something like attach but I have not seen anything in the docs and I wanted to be sure I was not missing something obvious.

Comment: I see, well you can also look at the source at CPAN as well and I have not seen that possibility so you would have to create multiple instances and compare with each other.

Comment: In case there is no solution with dbd-sqlite I can always use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733581/merge-all-sqlite-databases-with-different-tables recipe and dump all dbs into one. The tables have different names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`do`](http://p3rl.org/DBI#do) executes arbitrary SQL statements.

```
$dbh->do('attach foobar as foobar');
```

`foobar`'s tables are then queryable.

Answer (score 2):

You can even do this:

```
use DBI;
my $dbfile1 = 'test1.db'; # will be `main`
my $dbfile2 = 'test2.db'; # will attach as `other`
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile1","","") or die "dbh";
$dbh->do('attach ? as ?', undef, $dbfile2, 'other') or die "attach";
```