# Merging databases

Tags: android, sqlite, merge

At the moment I have apprx. 20 identical structured databases(SQLite) which I transferred from remote destinations (android phones) to my pc. Now I want to add them to a single one in order to perform data analysis on the data. How is this possible? The primary keys of the tables are auto-increment integer , so when using `ATTACH` I get a Primary key is not unique error. In addition it would be nice if i could somehow keep a reference between the rows and the tables which are coming from.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80801/how-can-i-merge-many-sqlite-databases

Comment: I have already read that but does not help me. I have less than 32 databases so ATTACH should be fine. But where do I use ATTACH from?

Comment: @JustCurious [per default, the `SQLITE_MAX_ATTACHED` is `10`](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_attached), not 32, so the other question provides the way to go.

Comment: ... you can inspect the actual limits of your SQLite instance by running `.limit` in the [CLI](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html).

Answer (score 2):

The way you worded the question, it sounds to me like it is a one-time operation you're doing on a home PC. I would probably just open a fresh database in the [sqlite shell](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) and attach/insert from/detach each database like they show on [that](https://web.archive.org/web/20120110035836/http://old.nabble.com/Attempting-to-merge-large-databases-td18131366.html) link.

If you need to script this, [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20081228211745/http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3080) has an example of embedding sqlite into shell scripts.  More preferably, you could code it up with your favorite language's sqlite bindings, like [Python's](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Since the most important links are dead now, the answer might be not as useful anymore. Do you see any chance to refresh it?

Comment: Updated with wayback machine links where I could.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tried to make the content of the link targets a bit clearer. I hope you don't find this a degradation, if you do, please just undo it. BTW, I in your place would make the three basic steps of this approach more visually stand out (maybe by a bulleted list?).

Answer (score 0):

### Limit for attached Databases

Use **Attach – Copy – Detach**. This is the approach that's already [explained by dokkaebi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9057584/2932052).

### Remaining Part

> The primary keys of the tables are auto-increment integer, so when using ATTACH I get a Primary key is not unique error. In addition it would be nice if i could somehow keep a reference between the rows and the tables which are coming from.

#### Primary key

Add a column for the new primary key (i.e., `mid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`), its name has to be different to the original primary key (I'd suggest integrating the original primary key as a data column into the target table(s)).

#### Source Database indication

Add a column for the source database (i.e., `src`) to the table(s) in the target database, it will be filled by a string literal within the `select`.

So if a table in the source databases looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE ATab(
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`,
   x, 
   y,
   ...);
```

your destination database should have a corresponding table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ATab(
   mid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`,
   src TEXT,
   id INTEGER, 
   x, 
   y,
   ...);
```

Then for filling the destination table with data from the source table in the attached database `db1` (`ATTACH 'db1.db' AS toMerge;`), you change

```sql
INSERT INTO ATab SELECT * FROM toMerge.ATab;
```

into

```sql
INSERT INTO ATab (src, id, x, y, ...) SELECT 'db1' AS src, * FROM toMerge.ATab;
```

In the insert statement, you specify all the columns that you fill in explicitly by the select, while omitting the primary key: It is (implicitly) filled in automatically by SQLite.

Since you are dealing with many databases to import from, it would indeed be a good idea to script this process to avoid annoying copy-paste errors.