# list spasial file type in a folder in android

Tags: android, file, list

I want to list only .db files in a folder and join them to one db file..At this time I am just able to list all files in my folder..Can some one help me how to filter .db files?and then whats the best way to join this database files in one file?
Here is my code

```
public List<String> directoryPath(File path) {
    List<String> item = null;
    if( path.exists() && path.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
                public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                    return filename.endsWith(".db");     
                }
            });
        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)

        {

          File file = files[i];

           item.add(file);

        }


    }
    return item;
}
```

I edited my code and now I get null ponter access in `item` Can some one helps me abut this?why I get this error?
I call this code with this way

```
File path=new File(ClubCP.SDcardPath);
    Log.i("database_list","call list files");
    List<String> file_lists =   main.directoryPath(path);
    Log.i("database_list","list adapter");
    ListView Database_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.database_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            file_lists);
    Database_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implement the [FileFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileFilter.html)  (or [FilenameFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)) interface and pass that object to the `File.listFiles(File[name]Filter)` method.

```
public void directoryPath(File path) {
    if( path.exists() && path.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
                public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                    return filename.endsWith(".db");     
                }
            });
        // files only contains files that end with .db
    }
}
```

To merge database files you're not really on the right track.  You can't just append one database file to the end of the other.  You have to actually load one file using sql and then copy the tables ano in sql.  [How can I merge many sqlite databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80801/how-can-i-merge-many-sqlite-databases)

Comment: Thanks a lot,But now I have a problem..If I want to populate this list of files to an list view I need to return result in int format right?How can I convert file[] to int?

Comment: About database I searched too and I find that I must use attach method to join database files that user is selected..I think I must use a loop to do that right?

Answer (score 1):

check if files[i].getName().endsWith(".db")