# How can I create an in-memory database with sqlite?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm trying to create an in-memory database using `sqlite3` in Python.

I created a function to create a db database file and store information in to it and that is working 100%.

But trying to connect with `:memory:` I've faced some problems.

What I'm doing is:

```
import sqlite3

def execute_db(*args):
    db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cur = db.cursor()
    data = True
    try:
        args = list(args)
        args[0] = args[0].replace("%s", "?").replace(" update "," `update` ")
        args = tuple(args)
        cur.execute(*args)
        arg = args[0].split()[0].lower()
        if arg in ["update", "insert", "delete", "create"]: db.commit()
    except Exception as why:
        print why
        data = False
        db.rollback()
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return data
```

1. create name table

   ```
   execute_db("create table name(name text)")
   ```

   which returned `True`
2. insert some information to this table

   ```
   execute_db("insert into name values('Hello')")
   ```

   which returned

   ```
   no such table: name
   False
   ```

Why doesn't this work? It works when I use a file:

```
db = sqlite3.connect("sqlite3.db")
```

Comment: Why the double `db.commit()` when altering data?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ohh, my bad thank u.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You create a **new** connection each time you call the function. Each connection call produces a **new** in-memory database.

Create the connection outside of the function, and pass it into the function, or create a [shared memory connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681761/how-can-i-attach-an-in-memory-sqlite-database-in-python/32681822#32681822):

```
db = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")
```

However, the database will be *erased* when the last connection is deleted from memory; in your case that'll be each time the function ends.

Rather than explicitly call `db.commit()`, just use the database connection [as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

```
try:
    with db:
        cur = db.cursor()
        # massage `args` as needed
        cur.execute(*args)
        return True
except Exception as why:
    return False
```

The transaction is automatically committed if there was no exception, rolled back otherwise. Note that it is safe to commit a query that only reads data.

Comment: but if i create shared memory connection is this connection Fast as memory connection ?

Answer (score 6):

I created a dataframe and dumped it into a memory db with a shared cache:

```
#sql_write.py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('file:cachedb?mode=memory&cache=shared')
cur  = conn.cursor()

df
          DT      Bid      Ask
0         2020-01-06 00:00:00.103000  1.11603  1.11605
1         2020-01-06 00:00:00.204000  1.11602  1.11605
...                              ...      ...      ...
13582616  2020-06-01 23:59:56.990000  1.11252  1.11256
13582617  2020-06-01 23:59:58.195000  1.11251  1.11255

[13582618 rows x 3 columns]


df.to_sql("ticks", conn, if_exists="replace")
```

Read from the memory db in another thread / script:

```
#sql_read.py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('file:cachedb?mode=memory&cache=shared')
cur  = conn.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from ticks", conn)

df
          DT      Bid      Ask
0         2020-01-06 00:00:00.103000  1.11603  1.11605
1         2020-01-06 00:00:00.204000  1.11602  1.11605
...                              ...      ...      ...
13582616  2020-06-01 23:59:56.990000  1.11252  1.11256
13582617  2020-06-01 23:59:58.195000  1.11251  1.11255

[13582618 rows x 3 columns]
```

Note that it's a 15-second read from in memory, on 1.35 million rows (python 2.7). If I pickle the same dataframe and open it, the read takes only 0.3 seconds: that was very disappointing to discover, as I was hoping to dump a huge table into memory and pull it up anywhere I wanted instantly. But there you go, pickle it is.