# MPI how to send and receive SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite, mpi

I have a big SQLite database to process, so I would like to use MPI for parallelization to accelerate the speed. What I want to do is sending a database from root to every slave, and sending the modified databases to root after slave add some table into it. I want to use `MPI_Type_create_struct` to create a datatype to store database, but the database is too complicated. IS there any other way to handle this situation? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You wouldn't normally send an entire database via MPI - that would be pointless as each MPI node can potentially access the database itself without needing the master node to send it the database. And you wouldn't normally access a SQLite database in parallel - because it is precisely the one database that is least suitable for concurrent writers. Maybe explain a bit more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Your problem starts with *big SQLite database*. This is the wrong choice of technology. The right choice depends on your data and what kind of processing you want to do and ranges from scalable DBMS, Big Data technologies to scientific domain decomposition.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for your reply. I have a 3D root system model (serial program) which is stored in a SQLite database, and I am trying to modify some parameters to change the model. Each computation would cost more than 40 mins, I have 9 parameters and each parameter have small step size to increase step by step.

Answer (score 2):

I recently dealt with a similar problem - I have a large MPI application that uses SQLite as a configuration store. Handling multi-process writes is a challenge with an embedded SQL database. My experience with this involves a massively parallel application (running up to 65,535 ranks) with a shared filesystem.

Based on the [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) from SQLite and some experience with database engines, there are a few ways to approach this problem. I am making the assumption that you are operating with a shared distributed file system, and multiple separate computers (a standard HPC cluster setup).

Since SQLite will block when multiple processes write to the database (but not read), reads will most likely not be an issue. Each process can run multiple SELECT commands at the same time without issue.

The challenge will be in the writing. Disk I/O is several orders of magnitude slower than computation, so generally this will be the bottleneck. Having said that, network communication may also be a significant slowdown, so how you approach the problem really depends on where the weakest link of your running environment will be.

If you have a fast network and slow disk speed, or if you want to implement this in the most straightforward way possible, your best bet is to have a *single* MPI rank in charge of writing to the database. Your compute processes would independently run SELECT commands until computation was complete, then send the new data to the MPI database process. The database control process would then write the new data to disk. I would not try to send the structure of the database across the network, rather I would send the data that should be written, along with (possibly) a flag that would identify what table/insert query the data should be written with. This technique is sort of similar to how a RDBMS works - while RDBMS servers do support concurrent writes, there is a "central" process in control of the ordering of write operations.

One thing to note is that if a process writes to the SQLite database, the file is locked for *all* processes that are trying to read or write to it. You will need to either handle the SQLITE_BUSY return code in your worker processes, register a callback to handle this, change the busy behavior, or use an alternate technique. In my application, I found that loading the database as an in-memory database, (https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) for the readers provided a good workaround. Readers access the in-memory database, but sent results to the controlling process for writes. The downside is that you will have multiple copies of the database in memory.

Another option that might be less network intensive is to do the reads concurrently and have each worker process write out to their own file. You could write out to separate SQLite database files, or even export something like CSV (depending on the complexity of the data). When writes are complete, you would then have a single process merge the individual files into a single result database file - see [How can I merge many SQLite databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80801/how-can-i-merge-many-sqlite-databases). This method has its own issues, but depending on where your bottlenecks are and how the system as a whole is laid out, this technique may work.

Finally, you might consider reading from the SQLite database and saving the data to a proper distributed file format, such as HDF5 (or using MPI IO). Once the computation is done, it would be pretty straightforward to write a script that would create a new SQLite database from this foreign file format.