# Dbplyr: in_schema to use the same connection for two different databases

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

For reasons I am not going to explain here, I need to use the same connection object to read two databases in dbplyr. I found some online resources, but I am not getting this right.
Please have a look at the reprex below.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Many thanks!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI) # main DB interface
library(dbplyr) # dplyr back-end for DBs
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dbplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     ident, sql
library(RSQLite)


##create the databases

df1 <- tibble(x=1:20,y=rep(c("a", "b"), 10))


df2 <- tibble(x=101:120,y=rep(c("d", "e"), 10))


con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db1.sqlite")

dbWriteTable(con,"mydata1",df1, overwrite=T)

dbDisconnect(con) # closes our DB connection



con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db2.sqlite")

dbWriteTable(con,"mydata2",df2, overwrite=T)

dbDisconnect(con) # closes our DB connection


## Now that I have created the two databases, I try reading them with the same connection object

con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite())


db1 <- tbl(con, in_schema("db1.sqlite","mydata1"))
#> Error: no such table: db1.sqlite.mydata1
db2 <- tbl(con, in_schema("db2.sqlite","mydata2"))
#> Error: no such table: db2.sqlite.mydata2


### but this fails miserably. How to fix it?
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If you write a native SQL command (not via R or dbplyr) can you access both tables at once?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your R syntax. I use essentially the same approach with multiple databases in an SQL Server environment.

This is a database configuration problem. Your two databases are not setup so that a single query can access a table in both databases.

For SQLite it looks like this can be done in native SQL (not via R) using the `ATTACH` command (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6824831/7742981) accepted answer). You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/80801/7742981) question helpful. Both these questions involve writing SQL directly, which I would recommend for your initial attempt as it avoids the additional layer of having R involved.

If you want to do this only via R then it probably looks something like the following:

```r
con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db1.sqlite")

dbExecute(con, "attach 'db2.sqlite' as db2;")

# test query
test_query = paste("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM db1.mydata1","\n"
                   "UNION ALL","\n"
                   "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM db2.mydata2")
dbGetQuery(con, test_query)
```

If the last command works then you know that a SQL query can (now) touch both databases so you can then try to use `in_schema` to connect to both.